# Windows IoT/UWP frequency measurement library

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, fft, uwp, windowsiot

On my raspberry pi I'm using Windows IoT. I have an app which receives vibration measurement data from a digital input of an arduino device. I'm reading the data from a serial port on the pi.

Now I want to calculate the frequency of the measured vibration signal. Is there any standard FFT library to do that? Do I have to consider anything regarding to use Windows IoT / UWP?

Comment: FFT is an algorithm. There are many implementations of that algorithm, typically found in libraries with other signal processing algorithms. A lot of them actually use hardware-specific techniquest to speed up processing, like SSE CPU instructions, specialized DSP chips, etc.  There is no "standard" implementation

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks! As I said I have a raspberry Pi running Windowas IoT. So I can use C# and build UWP apps. But I don't know what kind of FFT do I have to use, when the input ist a binary signal (pin high or low).

Comment: This has nothing to do with C# or IoT. This is a signal processing question. What's wrong with using the values as they are though?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You are right, it has nothing to do with IoT. But I think it is importent to know where or on what machine or OS the algorithm should run! And I think also, that it is important to know which programming language!?

Comment: Doesn't matter. You can implement the algorithm in any language, any OS. As for the edit, well, counting the pulses isn't that hard. Just increment  a field and every X seconds retrieve its value and compare it to the previous retrieved value. If you do this every 1 second you'll actually have the frequency.